# How to block second thread start until the first thread stop or how to lock the button when the thread is executed in Tkinter

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, neopixel

I have a problem with overlapping two threads. What is the best way to connect Tkinter and the method with an infinite loop inside to not freeze the entire gui. I have it realized in the form of two threads and control flags. Everything works except that I can run two animations at the same time, which causes a bad effect.

```
 def __init__(self, master):
            self.btnRainbowOn = Button(
                master, text="     Włącz     ", command=self.start_rainbow)
            self.btnRainbowOff = Button(
                master, text="Wyłącz", command=Animation.stop_animation)
            self.btnRainbowAllOn = Button(
                master, text="    Włącz    ", command=self.start_rainbow_all)
            self.btnRainbowOff2 = Button(
                master, text="Wyłącz", command=Animation.stop_animation)

    def start_rainbow(self):
        """Run rainbow animation on separate thread."""
        Animation.start_animation()
        thread = threading.Thread(
            target=Animation.rainbow_cycle, args=(strip,))
        thread.start()

    def start_rainbow_all(self):
        """Run rainbow animation on separate thread, all pixels at once."""
        Animation.start_animation()
        thread = threading.Thread(target=Animation.rainbow, args=(strip,))
        thread.start()
```

Other file with class Animation

```
    @classmethod
    def stop_animation(self):
        """Set flag to stop animation."""
        Animation.flag_animation_stop = True
        Animation.flag_animation_run = False

    @classmethod
    def start_animation(self):
        """Set flag to run animation."""
        Animation.flag_animation_stop = False
        Animation.flag_animation_run = True

    @staticmethod
    def rainbow_cycle(strip, wait_ms=20, iterations=1):
        """Draw rainbow that uniformly distributes itself across all pixels."""
        while (True):
            if (Animation.flag_animation_stop == True):
                Animation.color_wipe(strip, Color(0, 0, 0))
                return
            if (Animation.flag_animation_run == True):
                for j in range(256 * iterations):
                    for i in range(strip.numPixels()):
                        print("Animacja tęczy")
                        strip.setPixelColor(i, Animation.wheel(
                            (int(i * 256 / strip.numPixels()) + j) & 255))
                    strip.show()
                    time.sleep(wait_ms / 1000.0)

    @staticmethod
    def theater_chase_rainbow(strip, wait_ms=50):
        """Rainbow movie theater light style chaser animation."""
        for j in range(256):
            for q in range(3):
                for i in range(0, strip.numPixels(), 3):
                    strip.setPixelColor(i + q, Animation.wheel((i + j) % 255))
                strip.show()
                time.sleep(wait_ms / 1000.0)
                for i in range(0, strip.numPixels(), 3):
                    strip.setPixelColor(i + q, 0)
```

How to block the launch of one thread during the execution of the second or how to block the button for the duration of the thread. To prevent two animations from running simultaneously.

Comment: You need a thread because you use time.sleep. Instead, use the Tk window's `after` method to iterate your animation steps. ie: `self.after(wait_ms, animation.next_step)`. Then you can use timer events and keep it all in 1 thread.

Comment: use `root.after(time_ms, callback)` instead of `time.sleep()` and then you can run it without thread and have no problem to control widgets

Comment: if you need threads then animation could set variable in main thread - directly or using queue - which informs main thread to block/unblock button and run next animation. Main thread will need to use `after(time_ms, check_variables)` to check if variable is set and start next animation and block/unblock button using `button["status"]="disabled"`, `butto["status"]="normal"`. So you still need `after()`

Comment: Tkanks you wery much  for the answers. I'am finally using thead and tkinter after function to check that is thread active.